# Attribute "strokeWidth" has already been defined in telerik xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, telerik-appbuilder

```
1.Dimension types not allowed (at 'strokeWidth' with value '2dp').
2.Attribute "strokeWidth" has already been defined.
3.Attribute "strokeColor" has already been defined.
4.Attribute "fillColor" has already been defined.
```

Getting 4 error after adding the telerik dlls in xamarin project. any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it is clearly in the logcat you provided -- name conflicted

lib telerik has three attrs which is already been defined by xamarin.

`solution`: You can change the attr's name which been defined in xamarin or telerik.

Comment: Where can i change that ?

Comment: maybe `modulename` -> `src` -> `main` -> `res` -> `values` -> `attrs`, I do not know your project structure. I suggest you can use global search if you don't really know how to find :-)

Comment: i found that telerik's attrs xml file and try to change that but it is not modifing.

Comment: Consider compile it as a `module`. `.lib` can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

We (Telerik) would like to inform the community that based on customers' reports we managed to reproduce the reported behavior on our side with our latest official release. This allowed us to closely investigate the possible causes and we managed to find the root cause.

In order to fix the reported errors users should delete the reference of the *Telerik.Xamarin.Android.Gauges.dll* from their Android project. Deleting this reference should not be an issue for any user since the **RadGauge** component is not available in our UI for XamarinForms suite, yet.

Best regards, Pavlov.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.